# Facebook - Delete all friends requests via API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to delete all friends requests via API?

First get a list of Friends Requests and I could use loop to delete each one via API, FQL or something?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds a bit malicious if you ask me

Answer (score 2):

Facebook just provide access to get data to you from its tables. You cannot change any thing. I think it is impossible. Even if it is possible then it is totally illegal. You can only retrieve information from facebook tables. You cannot do any other activity with those tables.

Comment: That is a shame, my friend is quite famous and he got over 10,000 friends requests. Damn... I have to delete it manually huh?

Comment: if your friend has received 10,000 requests, then you dont need to worry. Facebook only allows maximum 5000 friends. Above that even no body can send friend request

Answer (score 2):

in this page
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

they said that

> To read the requests sent to the
>   user:
>
> GET /me/apprequests/
>
> Or, you can read a request if you know
>   the request id:
>
> GET /ID/
>
> To delete a request:
>
> DELETE /ID/

but this will just work for the same application
not for all application

Answer (score 0):

You can delete app_requests from friends, but not friend requests.